# How to read a file in systemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I have a file with multiple lines with the following structere

r,ACFE13D5,00000000

w,FE1234AC,00000000

The mid value is hexa adreess, and the last value should be data with lengh of 32 bit(also hexa).

What is the simple way ro read such a file and get the values into the following transaction prototype:

```
  direction_enum   rw;  // where-      typedef enum { READ = 0, WRITE = 1 }                          direction_enum;

   bit [31:0] addr; 
   bit [31:0] data;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $fscanf

```
int fd; // file descriptor
byte mode;
int status;
fd = $fopen("filename","r");
status = $fscanf("%c,%h,%h",mode,addr,data); 
if(status != 3) error;// you did not read in 3 values
case(mode)
"r": rw=READ;
"w": rw=WRITE;
default: error;
endcase
```

Comment: @dave_59- Shouldn't I add some for statement for running all the lines in the file?

Comment: @dave_59- so the command                                                               status = $fscanf("%c,%h,%h",mode,addr,data); "scan" only the first line, right?